# How to setting up the custom size thumbnail for wp_get_attachment_thumb_url()?

Tags: images

I made a line of code to display a product category thumbnail on WordPress. The problem is, the size of my thumbnail is 150x150. I need to set in higher dimension. Try to apply thumbnail size but have no result, the thumbnail still 150x150 pixel.

Here my code:

```
$cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
$cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id );

?><img src="<?php if ( $cat_thumb_url ) {
       echo $cat_thumb_url ;
    } else {
       echo mytheme_catch_that_image();
    }
?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>"/>
```

Comment: if images were uploaded before the size was changed, the thumbnails need to be regenerated for the new sizes to be created.

Comment: Already regenerate, but the result still 150x150

Comment: [This answer](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-custom-image-size-in-wp_get_attachment_url) might help.

Comment: Follow the link from you, unfortunately displayed the last image uploaded. Not the category's thumbnail itself. @Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant you should use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` with your `$cat_thumb_id`. Try this:

```
$cat_thumb_id  = get_woocommerce_term_meta($cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
$cat_thumb     = wp_get_attachment_image_src($cat_thumb_id, 'medium_large');
$cat_thumb_src = $cat_thumb[0] ? esc_url($cat_thumb[0]) : mytheme_catch_that_image();

?><img src="<?php echo $cat_thumb_src; ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>"/>
```